# What happens when casting `int*` to pointer to bitset

Tags: c++, bitset, static-cast

I am doing a simple test, calculating the number of 1's in a number's binary representation:

```
  int x;
  while (cin >> x) {
      bitset<32> xBitmap = {0};
      xBitmap = static_cast<bitset<32>>(x);
      std::cout << xBitmap.count() << std::endl;
  }
```

The above code creates the right result, but when I use a pointer to a bitset, something unexpected happens:

```
      bitset<32>* xBitmap = nullptr;
      xBitmap = static_cast<bitset<32>*>((void*)&x);
      std::cout << xBitmap->count() << std::endl;
```

This code creates random results, every use of "count()" creates a different result. I am guessing this is a memory leak? But why would it cause a memory leak?

Answer (score 2):

### What is happening in your first example?

You have a variable of type `int` and you perform a `static_cast` to convert the `int` to a `std::bitset<32>`. From the specification of `static_cast` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)):

> `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`
>
> 1. If there is an implicit conversion sequence from `expression` to `new_type`, or if overload resolution for a direct initialization of an object or reference of type `new_type` from `expression` would find at least one viable function, then `static_cast<new_type>(expression)` returns the imaginary variable `Temp` initialized as if by `new_type Temp(expression);`, which may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of `new_type` or a call to a user-defined conversion operator.
>
> ...

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A(int x) { std::cout << "A " << x << std::endl; }
};

int main(void) {
  int y = 13;
  A a = static_cast<A>(y);
}
```

Running this program will print `A 13`. This means that in this case `A a = static_cast<A>(y)` is equivalent to `A a = A(y)`. This is because `y` is of type `int` and there is a constructor for `A` that takes an `int`.

If we would change the example so that the constructor for `A` takes an `std::string`, the program would no longer compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
  A(std::string x) { std::cout << "A " << x << std::endl; }
};

int main(void) {
  int y = 13;
  A a = static_cast<A>(y);
}
```

The compiler would complain about being unable to convert an `int` to `A`.

Consider a third example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A(int x) { std::cout << "A " << x << std::endl; }
};

class B {
public:
  B(A a) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void) {
  int y = 13;
  B b = static_cast<B>(y);
}
```

This example compiles and prints:

```
A 13
B
```

So this would be what the specification calls an "implicit conversion sequence". While there is no constructor for `B` that takes an `int`, there is a constructor for `B` that takes an `A` and then there is a constructor for `A` that takes an `int`. So `static_cast<B>(y)` would resolve to to `B(A(x))`. If we would add the `explicit` keyword to the constructor for `A`, then the example would no longer compile:

```
  explicit A(int x) { std::cout << "A " << x << std::endl; }
```

This is because the `explicit` keyword on a constructor forbids the constructor from being used in a implicit conversion sequence.

These examples allow us to understand what is happening when we call `static_cast<std::bitset<32>>(x)`. The `std::bitset<N>` class has a constructor that takes an `unsigned long` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset)). The constructor is not marked with the `explicit` keyword, so it can participate in an implicit conversion sequence. An `int` can be implicitly converted to an `unsigned long`. So `static_cast<std::bitset<32>>(x)` resolves to `std::bitset<32>((unsigned long)x))`, so it creates a new instance of `std::bitset<32>` with the value of `x` passed to the constructor.

This is why your first example works.

### What is happening in your second example?

You have a variable of type `int`. You create a pointer to this variable (`&x`) and then you cast the pointer to a `void` pointer. Then you `static_cast` the `void` pointer to a `std::bitset<32>` pointer. From the specification of `static_cast` ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)):

> 10. A prvalue of type pointer to `void` (possibly cv-qualified) can be converted to pointer to any object type.

So unlike your first example, your second example will not create a new instance of `std::bitmap<32>`. Rather, `xBitmap` points to the memory address of `x`, but interprets this memory as an `std::bitmap<32>`. However, there is a problem with that: The memory size of a `std::bitmap<32>` may not be equal to the memory size of an `int`. This is implementation-specific, so different implementations of the C++ standard library may have different sizes for `std::bitmap<32>`.

On my system, using the C++ standard library that comes with GCC, the following code will print `8`:

```
std::cout << sizeof(std::bitset<32>) << std::endl;
```

This means that a `std::bitset<32>` takes 8 bytes of memory. While the 32 bit could of course be represented by only 4 bytes, it seems that on my system the `std::bitset` will always allocate multiples of 8 bytes (i.e. unsigned long). So for example `sizeof(std::bitset<1>)` is also `8`, and so is `sizeof(std::bitset<64>)`, but then `sizeof(std::bitset<65>)` is 16 and so is `sizeof(std::bitset<128>)`, but then `sizeof(std::bitset<129>)` is 24 and so on.

Whereas (on my system), an `int` takes only four bytes. So when we take the memory of an `int` but interpret it as `std::bitmap<32>`, we would read 8 bytes (the size of an `std::bitmap<32>`) from a memory allocation that is only of size 4 bytes. So we would read an additional four bytes after the memory of the `int`. There could be anything in this memory, so the read results in undefined behavior. This is why you get the random values when you call `count()`. It will count the number of bits in the `int`, but also the number of bits in the four bytes after that.

Modern compilers such as GCC and Clang have a feature called "Address Sanitization" ([ASan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer)), which can help you debug such memory issues. For GCC, it can be enabled with the `-fsanitize=address` flag:

```
$ g++ -fsanitize=address test.cpp
$ ./a.out
123
=================================================================
==16616==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd1c7c5f80 at pc 0x55b34fd334b3 bp 0x7ffd1c7c5f00 sp 0x7ffd1c7c5ef0
READ of size 8 at 0x7ffd1c7c5f80 thread T0
```

So in this case, address sanitization detects that your program attempts to read past the size of an allocation.

So with regards to the part of your question about memory leaks: This is not a memory leak, but a buffer overflow. A memory leak would be when you allocate memory and then forget to free the memory.

Comment: Thank your very much!  I never think bitset's implementation would be this way. Your explanation is really helpful!

Comment: is it right called "buffer overflow"？I don't allocate memory, just read memory out of boundary, and it causes undefined results, so isn't "memory leak" right?

Comment: When you declare a local variable such as `int x`, your program will allocate the memory for this variable on the stack (hence why ASan reports a stack buffer overflow). Whether buffer is the right word for the memory of a local variable is debatable. I guess you could also call it local variable overflow, but I never heard anyone say this before, whereas for buffer overflow, everyone will understand what you mean. Memory leak is something different, it refers to the situation where you have declared a memory without releasing it, i.e. a `new` without a corresponding `delete`.

Comment: "out-of-bounds read" would be another common description you could use.

Comment: i stil have a problem. the first situation, sizeof (xBitmap) is also 8bytes, but why would it count only 4bytes?

Comment: The source code of the std::bitset from the GCC stdc++ lib can be found [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/596676d66cab21e5ed85669e737af5b62f067d57/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset#L751). You can see that it uses a base class `_Base_bitset`, which holds an array of unsigned longs, where the size of the array is the number of bits divided by 64 and rounded up. So for 4 Bytes, you would get an array of size one, so a single 8 Byte unsigned long. The counting happens in `_M_do_count`. It iterates over the array and uses the buildin `__builtin_popcountl` to count the bits.

Comment: So when you have a bitset<32>, it will still allocate the unsigned long, but the second half of the unsigned long will be zeros, so they do not change the bit count.